# Printing odd numbers from 1 to 999999 on separate lines using a nested loop

Tags: java

I am trying to do exactly what the title says. I have no clue how to begin this code other than the knowledge that it will most likely have to have a do-while loop with a body inside the 'while' portion enclosed in braces. I would like to understand this rather than get a straight answer, so if you could either write a code and explain or give more hints at how to do it that would be greatly appreciated!
The output needs to look like this:

```
1 (new line)
1 3 (new line)
1 3 5 (new line)
.. ... (new line)
.. ... ... (new line)
1 ... ... 999997 (new line)
1 ... ... 999997 999999
```

(It is not letting it show that it increases by 1 odd number each line, so i denoted with "(new line)" I hope it is more readable now.)

OK, thanks to newproducts clarification i was able to write this:

```
    String line = "";
    int start = 1;

    for(;start <= 999999;)
        do{
            System.out.println(line);
            start += 2;
            line += " "  + start;
            }
        while(start <= 999999);
```

But i face a small problem, 1 does not appear at the start of any of the lines. What am I forgetting to do?

**RESOLVED. I added 1 + line to my print statement and it runs the way I want. Thank you to everyone who tried to help, especially newproduct who new what I needed even with me not wording my question properly.

Comment: They won't do your homework at SO. please attempt something, to get their help. Yeah I know they are Cruel. But hey, they are helping you learn.

Comment: Please show that you have made an attempt before seeking help

Comment: @Rohit Jain, I understand. I will try something here and update. My problem was how to begin.

Comment: C'mon. I know you can get this! Just try a bit more.

Comment: @RogerHamblin. Sure, we're here to help if you face any issue.

Comment: Do you realize that what you have described is printing out approximately 125 billion numbers?

Comment: @bengoesboom I am sorry, but it is hard to try something if you don't know how to begin. That's why I said I don't want just a code for an answer and that I would like to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the problem as the following:

each progressive line includes the content of the previous line plus another odd number. Therefore, it would make a lot of sense to always store the content of the previous line under a String variable, perhaps.

Now to find every odd number, start with the number 1 and add 2 each time until a given number (in this case 9999999999) is surpassed. The same thing can be done with evens -- you simply start with 2 instead of 1.

In a do-while loop structure, it would look something like this (pseudocode):

```
int lastnum = 1;
String prevLine = lastnum;

do while loop (999999 not passed)
{

    PRINT(prevline + " " + (lastnum + 2));

    lastnum += 2;

    \\update the information stored in the previous line
    prevLine += " " + lastnum;

}
```

In essence you want to:

1) Start with 1.
2) Print the previous line + the new number (for the first number, the previous line will be blank).
3) Update the previous line
4) Continue steps 2-3 until 999999999 is passed.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused on how to start and you breaking it down like that was exactly what I needed and wanted! I will post my code once I am finished! Again, Thank you!

Comment: That is a lot of string concatenations....

Comment: Are concatenations bad?

Comment: Thank you again! I updated with code i was able to write but I now face a small problem. the number 1 does not appear at the start of any of the lines. Do you know how I can resolve this?

Comment: You need to put 1 in the initial line. My pseudocode wasn't meant to be directly translated. 

There are a few ways to resolve this. The most obvious way is that you could set prevLine = 1 instead of prevLine = "".

Comment: Simply switch the order of the variables:

int lastnum = 1;
String prevline = lastnum;

If you are having problems with the integer-string conversion, use Integer.toString(i)

Comment: I just added 1 + line in the print statement and it works. Thank you very much for your help. I realize I am new to this site and did not word my question properly to ask it here, but I thank you for knowing exactly what I needed and responding. One more time, Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You want to try and approach problems step by step. You should notice that it would help to store the previous lines as that is an obvious pattern. Similarly, in solving your secondary problem (about number 1), you should notice that 1 should be the first number printed so the problem occurred when the loop just began.

If you keep applying this step-by-step approach, you will be able to solve many problems, even ones more complex.

Comment: @newproduct: [Yes, they are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm).

Comment: @Jason Wow, thank you for showing me this. I guess a better way of doing it would be to carry over the length of the string and increment it each time.

Comment: @newproduct: Use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop to get you started

Here's a sample of a 4 loop that counts odd numbers from `1` to `999` inclusive

```
int n = 999;

for(int i=1; i<= n; i+=2)
{

}
```

maybe you can try putting one for loop inside another and see if that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt the progression approach, that stores the previous results and adds one more to it thereby creating the result for next line because calculating same thing for every line is not a good idea.